# Haskell Megaparsec: how to show a traceback of all parsers that led up to an error?

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

Here's my toy file:

```hs
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Data.Void (Void)

type Parser = Parsec Void String

myParser :: Parser String
myParser = do
            d <- digitChar
            c <- letterChar
            return $ replicate (read [d]) c
```

Now from ghci, if I type `parseTest (myParser <?> "foo") "3a"` I get `"aaa"` as expected, but if I type `parseTest (myParser <?> "foo") "33a"` then I get:

```
1:2:
  |
1 | 33a
  |  ^
unexpected '3'
expecting letter
```

The error message makes sense in this simple case (I had to enter a letter instead of another digit) but when writing more complicated parsers, `letterChar` may appear in any number of composite parsers, so it's not clear *which* `letterChar` was the one that failed. Since I passed in a label `foo` for my parser, I would like it if the error message instead said something like the following:

```
1:2:
  |
1 | 33a
  |  ^
error while parsing foo:
  unexpected '3'
  expecting letter
```

And more generally, as long as I give my parsers labels using `<?>`, I would like the whole traceback of errors to be shown, like:

```
error while parsing grandparent:
  error while parsing parent:
    unexpected '3'
    expecting letter
```

Is there a way to do this in Megaparsec?

Comment: I think the difficulty is that there is no single traceback of parsers you're in the middle of. Suppose your parser is `expr <|> eof where expr = sum <|> product`. Parsec will descend into `expr`, try both `sum` and `product`, and if neither matches will try `eof`. If that doesn't match either, you finally have a parse error - but what are you in the middle of? You failed at the beginning of `sum` just as much as you did at `eof`, and at `product`.

Comment: As long as the composite parsers are labeled like `(expr <|> eof) <?> "expr_or_eof" where expr = (sum <|> product) <?> "sum_or_product"`, I would like an error message like `error while parsing expr_or_eof: error while parsing sum_or_product: unexpected foo, expecting bar`. That seems possible to me, or at least, I don't yet see why that would be impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Megaparsec has no built in support for doing this, but you can use its custom error machinery.

We can define a custom error type that adds a context label to an existing `ParseError`, together with a `ShowErrorComponent` instance to display it within the error message.  (The weird orphan `Ord` instance for `ParseError` here satisfies a technical requirement.  Custom errors need an `Ord` instance, but `ParseError` doesn't have one, so we have to derive one if we want to include a nested ParseError in our custom error.)

```
data ErrorWithLabel = ErrorWithLabel String (ParseError String ErrorWithLabel)
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- orphan instance needed for technical reasons
deriving instance Ord (ParseError String ErrorWithLabel)

instance ShowErrorComponent ErrorWithLabel where
  showErrorComponent (ErrorWithLabel l e) =
    "while parsing " <> l <> ",\n" <> parseErrorTextPretty e
```

By itself, this doesn't do anything, but we can modify the definitions of `<?>` and its non-operator equivalent `label` to make use of this custom error.  Specifically, we can modify them so they call the original Megaparsec definition of `label` which properly handles the case where a parser fails without consuming input (by presenting the label as the "lowermost" error) and then **also** handle the case where a parser fails after consuming input (by wrapping the error with an `ErrorWithLabel` context):

```
import Text.Megaparsec hiding (label, (<?>))
import qualified Text.Megaparsec as P
import Text.Megaparsec.Internal (ParsecT(..))
import qualified Data.Set as Set

label :: String -> Parser p -> Parser p
label l p = ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eeok eerr ->
  let addLabel e = FancyError (errorOffset e) .
        Set.singleton . ErrorCustom $ ErrorWithLabel l e
  in unParser (P.label l p) s cok (cerr . addLabel) eeok eerr

infix 0 <?>
(<?>) :: Parser p -> String -> Parser p
(<?>) = flip label
```

This works fine for your example:

```
λ> parseTest (myParser <?> "foo") "33a"
1:2:                                                                                                     
  |                                                                                                      
1 | 33a                                                                                                  
  |  ^                                                                                                   
while parsing foo,                                                                                       
unexpected '3'                                                                                           
expecting letter

λ> parseTest ((myParser <?> "parent") <?> "grandparent") "33a"
1:2:                                                                                                     
  |                                                                                                      
1 | 33a                                                                                                  
  |  ^                                                                                                   
while parsing grandparent,                                                                               
while parsing parent,                                                                                    
unexpected '3'                                                                                           
expecting letter
```

A full code example with some slightly more complicated labelling:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GHC2021 #-}

module Main where

import Text.Megaparsec hiding (label, (<?>))
import qualified Text.Megaparsec as P
import Text.Megaparsec.Internal (ParsecT(..))
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import qualified Data.Set as Set

data ErrorWithLabel = ErrorWithLabel String (ParseError String ErrorWithLabel)
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

deriving instance Ord (ParseError String ErrorWithLabel)

instance ShowErrorComponent ErrorWithLabel where
  showErrorComponent (ErrorWithLabel l e) =
    "while parsing " <> l <> ",\n" <> parseErrorTextPretty e

type Parser = Parsec ErrorWithLabel String

label :: String -> Parser p -> Parser p
label l p = ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eeok eerr ->
  let addLabel e = FancyError (errorOffset e) .
        Set.singleton . ErrorCustom $ ErrorWithLabel l e
  in unParser (P.label l p) s cok (cerr . addLabel) eeok eerr

infix 0 <?>
(<?>) :: Parser p -> String -> Parser p
(<?>) = flip label

repspec :: Parser String
repspec = (do
  d <- digitChar
  c <- letterChar <?> "a character to replicate"
  return $ replicate (read [d]) c)
  <?> "replication spec"

literal :: Parser String
literal = between (char '\'') (char '\'') (takeWhileP Nothing (/= '\'')) <?> "literal string"

comment :: Parser String
comment = "" <$ char ';' <* takeRest <?> "a comment"

expr :: Parser String
expr = (repspec <|> literal <?> "expression")
  <|>  (comment <?> "comment")

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (parseTest (expr <* eof))
  [ "3a"   -- parses okay

  , "33a"  -- while parsing expression,
  --  ^    -- while parsing repspec,
           -- unexpected '3'
           -- expected a character to replicate

  , "?"    -- unexpected '?'
  -- ^     -- expecting comment or expression

  , "'x"   -- while parsing expression,
  --   ^   -- while parsing literal string,
           -- unexpected end of input
           -- expecting '''
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This does exactly what I wanted. I wonder why this is not the default behavior in Megaparsec...